# Can't run latest Blender on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dependencies, blender

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (Kubuntu, actually) on a Lenovo ThinkPad L540.

I installed the latest Blender from the PPA repository like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt install blender
```

(The version string is `94552-4c0cca78eb4-0thomas~bionic0` and the description includes `This is version 2.8 obtained by pulling the last version in the master branch of the blender git repository.`  According to the Blender website, that should be 2.82a.)

Attempting to run this new blender gives the error:

> `/usr/lib/blender/blender: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVM-6.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I then discovered that my scrollback history wasn't set up right, so I don't have the list of packages installed when I ran the earlier commands.

I'd earlier (a year ago) installed Blender 2.80 manually (not from a `.deb` but from a tarball); that installation still opens without complaining about libraries.

I've searched the error and `libLLVM` online and found a suggestion to use `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v`, which (after checking the man page) I tried, but it had no effect; the error on trying to run the new blender is exactly the same, including in a new Konsole window.

1. How can I get the dependencies installed correctly so the program will open, and
2. Is there somewhere I should report this as a bug?

Comment: Perhaps bypass this slightly broken package and simply run: `sudo snap install blender --classic` ? On my 18.04 system this successfully installed Blender version: 2.82 (sub 7), branch: master, commit date: 2020-03-12 05:06, hash: 375c7dc4caf4, type: Release.

Comment: @andrew.46 I do prefer `.deb` installations, but thanks for the suggestion.  I don't like the overhead of snap packages and have thus far avoided them successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Do this to fix dependency error:

   ```
   sudo apt install llvm-6.0
   ```
2. You can report any bug to the maintainer here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex

Comment: Thanks for the link; I let him know.  That's his answer below and the dependency is fixed now.  :)

Comment: Hello,This problem is still in ubuntu 20.10+blender 2.91,any workaround?

Comment: @AlexLuya, Can you elaborate, after installing this dependency, the problem persists?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for reporting this, llvm-6.0 is now in the dependencies. An new build will be available soon.

Comment: Hello,this problem is still in ubuntu 20.10+blender 2.91,any workaround?Since it is hard to install llvm-6.0 in ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 0):

Attempted installation of Blender v2.92 using schiex's PPA onto Xubuntu Studio 20.04 appeared successful but does not run. Attempt from terminal reports a missing dependency. Installing llvm-6.0 has fixed this; it now runs (at least to the splash screen ---I have not done more than that at this time).

Comment: This should be comment not question.